# Is this HashSet test example possible?

Tags: equals, hashcode, hashset

Yesterday I had a technical interview and one of the tasks was to explain the test example below. Is this possible and in which cases?

```
void test() {
   A a = new A();
   B b = new B();
   C c = new C();

   HashSet set;

   set = new HashSet();
   set.add(a);
   set.add(b);
   set.add(c);
   assert set.size() == 3;

   set = new HashSet();
   set.add(a);
   set.add(c);
   set.add(b);
   assert set.size() == 2;
}
```

Please help me!

Comment: Since it will give 3 instead of 2, I think 2nd test case will fail.

Comment: @Nikson K John: not necessarily - if `equals()` and `hashCode()` of class `C` are implemented in really *ugly way* it's *possible* that both tests pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to its spec, HashSet.add adds an element

> if this set contains no element e2 such that (e==null ? e2==null : e.equals(e2)

It would therefore be possible if the equals operation of the B and C classes were not symmetrical (`c.equals(b)` but `!b.equals(c)`).
Their hashes also need to be equals, since HashSet checks hashes before .equals if I remember correclty.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can achieve that behaviour with *really ugly code*! ***Never ever*** implement `equals` and `hashCode` as I've done (Java). The trick is that these methods should *change* their behaviour:

```
class A  {
  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return 0;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return o == this;
  }
}

class B  {
  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return 1;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return o == this;
  }
}

class C  {
  private static int counter = 0;

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    counter += 1;

    return 0;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (counter < 2)
      return o == this;

    return true;
  }
}
```

Class `C`'s `equals` as well as `hashCode()` *change* its behaviour after some calls.

Comment: Ooh yours is a nice answer involving a static counter. I tried to simplify mine by just assuming the same hash code for all three but just asymmetric equality overloads. But this is probably a more practical example of how to inadvertently get this kind of behavior where such a test could pass.

Comment: @Ike: yes, you're right: *asymmetric*, *unstable*, *intransitive* `equals` and `hashCode` can lead to these *"impossible"* outcomes. Just break the rule (my choice was *stable* when your is *symmetric*) and see.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @DmitryBychenko! That was helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean for both asserts to avoid failing in such a program, it could be possible if `A/B/C` override `GetHashCode` and `Equals` in a way such that the equality operator is not symmetric.

For simplicity let's assume that all elements are overriden to return the same hash code:

```
b==a -> false
c==a -> false
c==b -> false
b==c -> true
```

In that case for the first scenario:

```
  set.add(a);
  set.add(b);
  set.add(c);
```

We first insert `a` into the hash set. That's a given since it's empty. When inserting `b`, the hash set searches for duplicates by comparing `b==a` which evaluates to false (thus `b` is inserted). When inserting `c`, the has set evaluates `c==a` which is false, and `b==a` which evaluates to false (thus `c` is inserted).

Now for the second example:

```
   set.add(a);
   set.add(c);
   set.add(b);
```

The first line is the same. The second line compares `c==a` which evaluates to false, so `c` gets inserted. The third line then compares `b==c` which evaluates to true. As a result, `b` does not get inserted. The resulting hash set size is now 2 instead of 3, and both assertions succeed.

Of course, you need some really bizarre code overriding `GetHashCode` and `Equals` to have both `asserts` succeed, and the test would be indicative of some really screwy logic (it'd be the kind of test that would indicate a problem if it *did* pass). But this is a possible way for this test to pass.